# Detecting Controls in VB.NET Forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote the code below to delete control in another VB.NET Form; that workd fine; But the code cannot Detect that the Form has NO Controls; What is wrong with the code please:

```
Sub DeleteControls() ' WORKING
    For i As Integer = Form2.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim ctrl = Form2.Controls(i)
        ctrl.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub

Sub TestForm() ' NOT WORKING
    If Form2.Controls Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 has No Controls")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to count the controls on form 2.
"
Dim GetControls As Integer = Form2.Controls.Count"

Then Check if GetControls is smaller then 1 "No controls"

```
Sub TestForm()
    Dim GetControls As Integer = Form2.Controls.Count
    If GetControls < 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 has No Controls")
    End If
End Sub
```